# Download file in powershell script

Tags: javascript, powershell, https, download

I'm trying to find a method of downloading a file in a powershell script. From the website side I can see the URL as:

```
https://website.com/admin/listCC.cfm?reportCode=105&clientId=11111&beginDate=04/01/2016 00:00&endDate=04/01/2016 23:59&download
```

Clicking the link in IE would give a save, save as, or open prompt and it is a TXT file. I've tried using webclient code as well invoke-webrequest but the output is always like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Session Timed Out</title>

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function sessionDone(){
        alert('Your session has expired.  Please login again.');
        window.location = "/admin/logout.cfm";
        }
    //-->
    </SCRIPT>


    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />

    </head>
    <body onLoad="sessionDone();">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

I figured it out. I must have not been logging in properly with the initial invoke-webrequest code i was using. Here is what i'm using now

```
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
$loginsession=$null
$loginform=$null
$loginpage=$null
$login=$null
$dl_105=$null


$loginpage = Invoke-WebRequest ("https://website.com/loginpage") -SessionVariable loginsession
$loginform=$loginpage.Forms[0]
$loginform.fields["username"] = "username"
$loginform.fields["password"] = "password"

$login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://website.com/" + $loginform.Action) -WebSession $loginsession -Method POST -Body $loginform.Fields


$dl_105=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://website.com/admin/listCC.cfm?reportCode=105&clientId=11111&beginDate=$yesterday 00:00&endDate=$yesterday 23:59&download") -Method GET -ContentType "text/csv" -Body $loginform.Fields -WebSession $loginsession
Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\new_test.txt -InputObject $dl_105.Content -encoding ASCII

sleep 5
```

I was lucky that the download link I was trying to get to wasn't entirely unique. All I'm doing is passing in yesterday's date to get the file i needed.

Comment: looks like it's missing the cookies on the request that fetched that page.

Comment: Dan, thank you for the reply. Any idea on how to pass along the cookies in the request?